# Got Segmentation fault while implementing stack using Linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I am implementing stack using a linked list as it is given to us in college but am not able to remove the segmentation fault as I have not much idea about a segmentation fault. I am putting my code here. please tell my mistake and the reason so that not repeat this mistake again_/_

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {   int data;   struct node *next; }; 
struct node *top = NULL;

//push function representation 
void push (int x) {   
    struct node*newnode;
    newnode = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
    newnode->data = x;
    newnode->next = top;
    top = newnode;
}

//traverse function representation
void traverse () 
{
    struct node*temp;
    temp = top;

    if (top == NULL)
    {
      printf ("Stack is empty, please push some element");
    }   
    else
    {
        while (top != NULL)
        {     
          printf ("The element(s) in Stack are %d", temp->data);
          temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

//peek function representation 
void peek () 
{   
    if (top == NULL)
    {
      printf ("Stack is empty");
    }   
    else
    {
        printf ("Top element is %d", top->data);
    } 
}

//pop function representation 
void pop ()
{   
    struct node *temp;   temp = top;   
    if (top == NULL)
    {
      printf ("This is underflow condition");
    }   
    else
    {
        printf ("%d", top->data);
        top = top->next;
        free (temp);
    } 
}

void main () 
{
   push (2);
   push (4);
   traverse ();
   peek ();
   pop ();
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. At a minimum it will tell you immediately which exact line of code triggers the seg fault. That's the minimum info you need for your own debugging and should be provided here. You can also use the debugger to step thru the code and examine state as it runs.

Comment: As I don't know much about debugger will you please tell me which debugger I have to use for the best results?

Comment: Just google it. It depends which OS you are using. If Linux then `gdb` is common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the `traverse` function is wrong:

```
  while (top != NULL)  // <---- ups
  {     
    printf ("The element(s) in Stack are %d", temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
```

`temp` will become NULL when you reach the end of the list but since your check is done on `top`, you'll dereference the NULL and your program will crash.

It shall be:

```
  while (temp != NULL)  // <---- fixed
  {     
    printf ("The element(s) in Stack are %d", temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
```